# Find path with least maximun difference in a 2D array

Tags: dynamic, path, 2d, minimum

A network system is defined as a two-dimensional grid. Each cell of the grid has a routing coefficient associated with it. You need to send a packet from the top-left corner to the bottom right corner.

A packet can travel in four directions only - up, down, left and right and only if the cell does not go beyond bounds. A packet needs an energy of |C[x, y] - C[x', y']| to travel from the cell (x,y) to the cell (x', y'), where |x| denotes the absolute value of x.

The effort required by a packet in any path is defined as the maximum energy needed by the packet along that path. Your task is to find the minimum effort required by the packet to traverse the network from top-left corner to the bottom-right corner.

Consider, for example, the packet travels in the given grid with number of rows, N = 3 and number of columns, M = 4. as described below -

```
{{5,1,3,2},
 {7,4,1,8},
 {6,7,5,9}}
```

Suppose the packet travels from 5 → 1 → 4 → 7 → 6 → 7 → 5 → 9. Here the corresponding energies required for each of the transations are 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4 respectively. Hence the effort required in the path is 4.

Input Format

The first line contains two space-separated integers, N and M denoting the number of rows and number of columns respectively. N lines follow. Each line contains M integers denoting the

row of the grid.

Constraints

```
1<=N,M<=300
1<C(i,j)<1000000
```

Output Format

In a single line of output, print the minimum possible effort.

here is my solution but it gets timed out in some tests so can anyone suggest better solution?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

class Result {
    public static int getMinEffort(List<List<Integer>> C) {

        Node start = new Node(new Cell(0,0),new ArrayList<Cell>(),0);
        ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
        nodes.add(start);
        Cell destination = new Cell(C.size()-1,C.get(0).size()-1);


        while(true){
            Node active = nodes.get(0);
            nodes.remove(active);

            //break condition
            if(active.getCell().equals(destination)){
                return active.getEffort();
            }
            //checking neighbours

            active.getPath().add(new Cell(active.getCell().getX(),active.getCell().getY()));
            if(active.getCell().getX()>0){
                Cell neigh = new Cell(active.getCell().getX()-1,active.getCell().getY());
                if(!active.getPath().contains(neigh)) {
                    int effort = C.get(active.getCell().getX()).get(active.getCell().getY()) - C.get(neigh.getX()).get(neigh.getY());
                    if(effort<0)effort*=-1;
                    if(effort<active.getEffort()){
                        effort = active.getEffort();
                    }

                    nodes.add(new Node(neigh,active.getPath(),effort));
                }
            }
            if(active.getCell().getX()<C.size()-1){
                Cell neigh = new Cell(active.getCell().getX()+1,active.getCell().getY());
                if(!active.getPath().contains(neigh)) {
                    int effort = C.get(active.getCell().getX()).get(active.getCell().getY()) - C.get(neigh.getX()).get(neigh.getY());
                    if(effort<0)effort*=-1;
                    if(effort<active.getEffort()){
                        effort = active.getEffort();
                    }

                    nodes.add(new Node(neigh,active.getPath(),effort));
                }
            }
            if(active.getCell().getY()>0){
                Cell neigh = new Cell(active.getCell().getX(),active.getCell().getY()-1);
                if(!active.getPath().contains(neigh)) {
                    int effort = C.get(active.getCell().getX()).get(active.getCell().getY()) - C.get(neigh.getX()).get(neigh.getY());
                    if(effort<0)effort*=-1;
                    if(effort<active.getEffort()){
                        effort = active.getEffort();
                    }

                    nodes.add(new Node(neigh,active.getPath(),effort));
                }
            }
            if(active.getCell().getY()<C.get(0).size()-1){
                Cell neigh = new Cell(active.getCell().getX(),active.getCell().getY()+1);
                if(!active.getPath().contains(neigh)) {
                    int effort = C.get(active.getCell().getX()).get(active.getCell().getY()) - C.get(neigh.getX()).get(neigh.getY());
                    if(effort<0)effort*=-1;
                    if(effort<active.getEffort()){
                        effort = active.getEffort();
                    }

                    nodes.add(new Node(neigh,active.getPath(),effort));
                }
            }

            Collections.sort(nodes);
        }

    }

    static class Node implements Comparable<Node>{
        private Cell cell;
        private List<Cell> path = new ArrayList<>();
        private int Effort;

        public Node(Cell cell, List<Cell> path, int effort) {
            this.cell = cell;
            this.path = path;
            Effort = effort;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Node o) {
            if (o.getEffort()>Effort){
                return -1;
            }else if(o.getEffort()==Effort){
                return 0;
            }else {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        public Cell getCell() {
            return cell;
        }

        public void setCell(Cell cell) {
            this.cell = cell;
        }

        public List<Cell> getPath() {
            return path;
        }

        public void setPath(List<Cell> path) {
            this.path = path;
        }

        public int getEffort() {
            return Effort;
        }

        public void setEffort(int effort) {
            Effort = effort;
        }
    }

    static class Cell {
        private int x;
        private int y;

        public Cell(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (!(o instanceof Cell)) return false;
            Cell cell = (Cell) o;
            return x == cell.x &&
                    y == cell.y;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(x, y);
        }
    }

}

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int r = scanner.nextInt();
        int c = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();

        List<List<Integer>> C = new ArrayList<>(r);

        for(int i = 0;i<r;i++){
            ArrayList<Integer> col = new ArrayList<>(c);
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] num = input.split(" ");
            for(int j =0;j<c;j++){
                col.add(Integer.parseInt(num[j]));
            }
            C.add(col);
        }
        int result = Result.getMinEffort(C);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

depth first with binary search may help

```
public class PathWithMinimumEffort {


// **** global variable(s) ****
static boolean vis[][]      = null;
static boolean arrived      = false;
static int effort           = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
static final int[][] dirs   = { {0,1}, {1,0}, {0,-1}, {-1,0} };

// **** global variables to generate gate ****
static int left     = 0;
static int right    = 1000000;

static int dfs(int[][] heights, int row, int col, int gate) {

    // **** get the number of rows and columns ****
    int rows = heights.length;
    int cols = heights[0].length;

    // **** base case (lower-right cell) ****
    if (row == rows - 1 && col == cols - 1) {
        arrived = true;
        return heights[row][col];
    }

    // **** flag that this cell as been visited ****
    vis[row][col] = true;

    // **** recurse in all possible directions O(rows * cols)****
    for (int i = 0; i < dirs.length; i++) {

        // **** next cell ****
        int r = row + dirs[i][0];
        int c = col + dirs[i][1];

        // **** ****
        if (r >= 0 && r < rows && c >= 0 && c < cols && 
            !vis[r][c] && 
            Math.abs(heights[row][col] - heights[r][c]) <= gate) {

            // **** recursive call ****
            int ph = dfs(heights, r, c, gate);

            // **** current effort between cells ****
            int ce = Math.abs(heights[row][col] - ph);

            // **** update effort ****
            effort = Math.max(effort, ce);
        }
    }

    // **** return height of current cell ****
    return heights[row][col];
}


/**
 * Generate the next value of a binary search.
 * Set gate == -1 to initialize.
 */
static int genGate(int gate) {

    // **** initialization ****
    if (gate == -1) {
        left    = 0;
        right   = 1000000;
        return right / 2;
    }

    // **** done ****
    if (left > right) {
        return gate;
    }

    // **** compute mid value ****
    int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;

    // **** go left ****
    if (arrived) {
        right = mid - 1;
    }

    // **** go right ****
    else {
        left = mid + 1;
    }

    // **** update gate ****
    gate = left + (right - left) / 2;

    // **** return gate ****
    return gate;
}



static int minimumEffortPath(int[][] heights) {

    // **** get number of rows and columns ****
    int rows = heights.length;
    int cols = heights[0].length;

    // **** sanity checks ****
    if (rows <= 1 && cols <= 1)
        return 0;


    // **** loop incrementing the gate ****
    // for (int gate = 0; gate < 1000000; gate++) {

    //     // **** loop pass initialization ****
    //     arrived = false;
    //     effort  = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    //     vis     = new boolean[rows][cols];

    //     // **** start recursion  ****
    //     dfs(heights, 0, 0, gate);

    //     // **** if reached bottom-right cell; we are done ****
    //     if (arrived)
    //         break;
    // }


    // **** initial gate ****
    int gate = genGate(-1);

    // **** ****
    boolean done = false;
    do {

        // **** loop pass initialization ****
        arrived = false;
        effort  = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        vis     = new boolean[rows][cols];

        // **** save for comparison ****
        int prevGate = gate;

        // **** start recursion  ****
        dfs(heights, 0, 0, gate);

        // **** generate new gate ****
        gate = genGate(gate);

        // **** matching values ****
        if (gate == prevGate)
            done = true;
    } while (!done);

    // **** return effort ****
    return effort;
}


/**
 * Test scaffolding.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // **** initialize random number generator ****
    Random rand = new Random();

    // **** target gate ****
    int targetGate  = rand.nextInt(1000000) + 1;

    // **** display target gate value ****
    System.out.println("main <<< targetGate: " + targetGate);

    // **** loop until target gate is found ****
    boolean done    = false;
    int gate        = genGate(-1);
    do {

        // **** save for comparison ****
        int prevGate = gate;

        // **** update arrived as needed ****
        arrived = (gate >= targetGate) ? true : false;

        // **** new gate ****
        gate = genGate(gate);

        // **** matching values ****
        if (gate == prevGate)
            done = true;
    } while (!done);

    // **** display gate ****
    System.out.println("main <<<       gate: " + gate);

    // **** open scanner ****
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // **** read number of rows and columns ****
    String[] rcStr = sc.nextLine().trim().split(",");

    // **** extract number of rows and columns ****
    int rows = Integer.parseInt(rcStr[0]);
    int cols = Integer.parseInt(rcStr[1]);

    // **** declare the array ****
    int[][] heights = new int[rows][cols];

    // **** loop populating the heights array ****
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {

        // **** ****
        String[] colsStr = sc.nextLine().trim().split(",");

        // **** ****
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            heights[r][c] = Integer.parseInt(colsStr[c]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("main <<< heights:");
    for (int[] rr : heights) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rr));
    }

    // **** close scanner ****
    sc.close();

    // **** find and display minimum effort for path ****
    System.out.println("main <<< output: " + minimumEffortPath(heights));
}
```

}